# jasny bootstrap file upload not showing file name in the input div after submit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I am using jasny bootstrap file upload with ajaxupload.js.

http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

I used following code. When I click on select file it is showing it in the input div.

But when I click submit and then try to select element it is not showing the name in the input div

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ffkj6/

```
<form method="post" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="upload-adm" class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
          <div class="input-append">
            <div class="uneditable-input span3" style="height:20px;">
                <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> 
                <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="btn btn-file">
                <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn adm-file-btn">
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```